# prior art for US 20150079942

Tags: patentability, novelty, us20150079942

In reference to the patent: [US20150079942](https://www.google.com/patents/US20150079942)

I am looking for prior art for US patent application 20150079942. I believe this invention has overly broad claims.
According to me invention has not at least inventive step. 
Could anyone indicate exemplary prior art.